# Getting DropDownList values

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdownbox

I have a problem with taking the values from a DropDownList. I understand how to put in a value and get that value out with using numbers but my problem I must a value such as FrBrb and then take that value in the code and set it to a value of 40 in my code. Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRiverTour" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem Value="FrBrd">French Broad</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="Nant">Tuck</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="Tuck">Nantahala</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is my DropDownList with the letter values in it. I have to use the value as these but can't use number values which would be very simple. The actual code to get these values and then use them in my calculations is the puzzling part. I don't know if I should define them then use an if statement to decide which is which and then do my calculations but how do I define them or is there an easier way?
Here is the rest of my code so far:

```
riverTour = Convert.ToDecimal(ddlRiverTour.SelectedValue);
baseTourFee = rafters * riverTour;
```

I know this code doesn't work here but I did have an if statement that looked like this:

```
if (rivertour = FrBrd)
{
  baseTourFee = rafters * 40;
}
```

But that seems like a lot more code than is needed and doesn't work very smoothly.

Comment: What defines the numerical value of each of the "words" in the ListItem items?  Is it an `enum` or something like that?  What you're asking the compiler to do is effectively impossible... it's like asking it to add "cat" and "dog" together and come out with 73

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using the `if` statement (except the *magic number*, 40). Especially if there are only a few options. What do you mean when you say it `doesn't work very smoothly`, can you elaborate?

Comment: @DGibbs When I say doesn't work smoothly it's more like when I try to use my if statement like the one above it says that the value isn't defined. I even define it but that doesn't seem right. how do I get the value out and use it in a an if statement? I could easily code that and get it working.

Comment: @freefaller I totally understand that it's something impossible and I wish I could use numbers cause then I would already be done and on to the next problem. It's just wanting me to get that value then somehow assign it a number or somehow else set it to those values.

Comment: @Reduls Which value/variable does the compiler say isn't defined?

Comment: @DGibbs - probably `FrBrd` which isn't quoted.  My guess is the OP is expecting it match the string return from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having some way of giving each of the "words" in your list of `<asp:ListItem>` elements a specific numerical value, you're asking the compiler to do an impossible task.

If you don't already have a way to specifically give them values, my suggestion would be to use an `enum` such as...

```
public enum RiverTourEnum
{
  FrBrd = 40,
  Nant = 50,
  Tuck = 60,
}
```

Then you can parse the value in the dropdown to the appropriate enum value and use the number that way...

```
 string ddVal = ddlRiverTour.SelectedValue;
 RiverTourEnum enumVal = (RiverTourEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(RiverTourEnum), ddVal);
 int riverTourVal = (int)enumVal;
```

This obviously makes the assumption that the "words" in the list have static values.  If not, then you need to look at a different way to "lookup" exactly what numeric value should be used at that particular time

---

After reading the question again (and comments under it), if you really want to use `if` statements, then you're probably after something like this...

```
string riverTour = ddlRiverTour.SelectedValue;
if (riverTour == "FrBrd")
{
  baseTourFee = rafters * 40;
}
else if (riverTour == "Nant")
...
```

Or a better approach would be...

```
switch(ddlRiverTour.SelectedValue)
{
  case "FrBrd" : 
    baseTourFee = rafters * 40;
    break;
  case "Nant" :
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just haven't been taught enums yet but I will go ahead and try it out. It seems like an impossible task like everyone is saying and I agree. Let me try your solution real quick and see if it works!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I looked through my code and I had my DropDownList value riverTour set as a dang decimal for some reason since that's what I had done in the last exercise. Thank you so much every time it's just some small little thing I missed! I have to do this for my radiobuttonlist but now I know what to do and once I get those running and get my calculations done and returned ill let you know how it worked! Ill set yours as the answer! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Great - glad you got it sorted @Reduls - good luck with the rest of your project :-)

Comment: I actually finished it a while back and it went pretty well! Thanks!